# What is the name of the equation P=IV?

Tags: power

Ohm's law is \$V=IR\$, but what is the equation \$P=IV\$ called? I've never heard anyone refer to it with a name, and my text books and wikipedia don't refer to it by any name.

Comment: It might be helpful to observe that the relationship between the voltage across and the current through a circuit element is what *defines* the circuit element.  For example, a resistor is defined as that circuit element that "obeys" Ohm's law.  However, there is nothing inconsistent about some other relationship, i.e., a "square law" circuit element:  \$i = k v^2 \$.  However, it is *always* the case that the power associated with a circuit element is the product of the voltage across and the current through and this is analogous to mechanical power \$P=Fv\$.  What is the name of that eq.?

Comment: I don't have a name for it.  In conversation, I wouldn't say "power is 6W by Joule's first law" I would just say "power is 6W by P equals I V". It's not really a law anyway, it follows automatically from the definitions of volt and amp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Informally, this is referred to as the "power law" or "power formula". It seems that there is a widespread practice to refer to it, incorrectly, as "Watt's law".

> However, note that the first term potentially conflicts with a widely used meaning of "power law" which describes any situation in which two quantities are related via any any power higher than 1: quadratically, or cubically, and so on. For example, if a doubling in some independent variable X causes some dependent variable Y to quadruple, then X and Y are linked by a power law.

It closely corresponds to what Wikipedia calls [Joule's first law](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%27s_laws):

$$Q = I^2 \cdot R  \cdot t$$

Watts is just \$P = \displaystyle\frac{Q}{t}\$, which reduces it to \$P = I^2R\$, and by Ohms we get all the variants.

It looks like there is justification in just calling all variations of the electric power law "Joule's First Law".

However, people (who otherwise know a thing or two about electronics, as well as Ohm's Law) might not understand "Joule's First Law". In casual conversation, in which I don't want to get uppity and educate people about terminology, I would call it the "voltage-current product law".

Comment: "Power law" isn't a good name because we often use that term to describe any situation where one quantity depends on a power of another quantity.

Comment: [Power Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law)

Answer (score 1):

It's embodied in [Joule's First Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%27s_first_law) .

Comment: Yes, but how do you refer to this equation in conversation?  Everyone knows what you mean if you say "Ohm's Law"...

Comment: @Bob How about, "voltage-current product law".

Answer (score 1):

This equation is exactly the Joule-Lenz law. Actually both equations:

\$dQ = I.U.dt\$ and \$P = I.U\$ are two forms of the same law, because it is known that the power is the first derivative of the energy: \$ \frac{dQ}{dt} = P = I.U\$

Such multi-forms of the laws is not something uncommon. Notice that the Ohm's law has three forms actually.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this varies regionally, but depending on the physical effect you're talking about or the type of power supply that is involved, you may refer to

- "electrical power"
- "dissipated power"
- "\$IV\$ power"
- "\$I^2R\$ power"
- "\$V^2/R\$ power"

It doesn't have a name-name that I've encountered in my career.